# Error when filtering code by date due to being 1st of the month

Tags: excel, vba

My code has been working for the past 2 weeks but for some reason now that it is the first of the month I am getting a 1004 error, saying autofilter method range class failed. I am assuming this is because it is day 1 of the month and it is trying to take 3 off of it.

For context I am trying to filter by dates and filter out the dates which are more than 3 days old.

```
Sub filtering_older_than_one_month()
Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, LstRw As Long

    Set sh = Sheets("modified_report")

Selection.AutoFilter
    Worksheets("modified_report").Range("A2:A2000").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="<" & CLng(Date - 3)
End Sub
```

When debugging I am getting an error on the line after selection.autofilter

For the macro to run and filter out accounts that are > 3 days old.

Comment: There is a dateadd function, if you put a negative it will subtract. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function That should handle the changing month/year

Comment: Thanks, I am trying it but I still cant figure how to incorporate it into the code. I currently have dateadd(d, -3, Now)

Comment: What's with the `Selection.AutoFilter` - is that just a line that shouldn't be in the question?

Comment: Perhaps, does it seem unnecessary?

Comment: Yes. Normally you don't want to work with `Selection`. And in this case it certainly sounds like you don't want to.

Comment: Ok, I will try and get rid of it, will that help with the error message I'm getting?

Comment: ```dateadd(d, -3, Now)``` Should be ```dateadd("d", -3, date)``` Now would be okay but if you don't need time might as well use date. The interval argument needs to be a string.

Comment: hmm, still seems to be creating the same error